# Print the panel's content to a PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I create a form:

[image]

The "button1" add new content to my panel and there is a scrollbar:

[image]

I want to save the content of my panel to a PDF. It's not very hard:

```
Bitmap MemoryImage;
using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "PDF file|*.pdf", ValidateNames = true })
            {
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate());
                    try
                    {
                        panelTombi.AutoSize = true;
                        panelTombi.Refresh();

                        int width = panelTombi.Width;
                        int height = panelTombi.Height;

                        MemoryImage = new Bitmap(width, height);
                        System.Drawing.Rectangle rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                        panelTombi.DrawToBitmap(MemoryImage, new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
                        iTextSharp.text.Image image1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance((System.Drawing.Image)MemoryImage, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        image1.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;


                        MemoryImage.Save("ttt.png"); // Pour voir l'image qui devrait être ajoutée dans le PDF
                        
                        //Save pdf file
                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(image1);

                        panelTombi.AutoSize = false;
                        panelTombi.Refresh();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
```

I save the content to a Bitmap, I create a PDF instance, I add the image to the PDF, I close the PDF.

In order to test that, I save the Bitmap to an image and it works:

[image]

but there is a problem in the PDF ...

[image]

The image seems to have a big zoom, the left part is missing as well as the bottom of the image.

Would you know where the error lies please?

I prefer to have a PDF to save on my computer because it is much easier to see the number of pages needed.

thank you in advance

Comment: check pdf pixel width. It looks like the image is too big for that. Use A3 paper size for the test or change the image size. For now, you get the image from the size of the panel. Does it work properly for different window / screen sizes?

Comment: `// image1.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
                        
                        image1.ScaleToFit(doc.PageSize);
         
                        image1.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);

                        MemoryImage.Save("ttt.png"); 

                        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create));
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(image1);`

But yet the image is not centered at top left, but ... bottom ...

Comment: One tricky thing to keep track of is that the y coordinate in the SetTextMatrix are a bit different from normal use of graphic coordinates, it works from the top bottom of the document, is backward. From this site - 
[c-sharpcorner](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-ii/)

Comment: Ok I understand how to set X and Y and that Y = 0 is bottom left corner and not top left corner.

But yet the problem is that I don't know how to set the Y, because for exemple Y = 50 the image is not located on the top of the page, but Y = 150 is too height because the upper part of the image is no longer visible because it exceeds the top of the sheet.

Comment: I'm not using iTextSharp, but the dpi parameter for the renderer might be the key. The page format (A4 etc.) has dimensions (in mm, e.g. 297 * 210), but it is not enough for printing. I'm sure you've heard of DPI units. For simplicity, this is the number of pixels you want to place on each inch of the paper on one axis. It was my first comment. Check width and lenght measured in pixels.
Finally - make sure that this parameter value is not exceeded for page width and length. Also do this  for any element of the page, otherwise it will be render inproperly.

Comment: I find this:

`image1.SetAbsolutePosition(0, (PageSize.A4.Height - doc.BottomMargin - doc.TopMargin - image1.ScaledHeight) / 2 + doc.TopMargin);`

Yet the image is at the top of the page, and centered :)

Answer (score 0):

Add this code only and create perfect pdf

```
image1.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_CENTER;
image1.ScaleToFit(PageSize.A4.Rotate().Width - 50f, PageSize.A4.Rotate().Height - 50f);
```